# Rails rescue if there's an error, contnue otherwise

Tags: ruby-on-rails

I've got a controller, where I want to rescue an exception, if it occurs, and redirect to a page, but continue on with the rest of the code if it doesn't. This is what i've got at the moment:

```
def confirm

rescue ActiveRecord::RecordInvalid
  redirect to "/used-postcode"
else

----rest of code----

end
```

What have I done wrong?

Answer (score 0):

Try:

```
def confirm
  begin
   #your code to rescue
  rescue ActiveRecord::RecordInvalid
    redirect to "/used-postcode" and return
  end

  #----rest of code----
end
```